# Pandas df.style.bar while maintaining rounding

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I apply the bar styling to a pandas dataframe after rounding I lose the rounding formatting, and I can't figure out how to apply the rounding formatting after because `df.style.bar` doesn't return a dataframe but a "Styler" object.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1.23456, 2.34567,3.45678],  'B':[2,3,4]})
df['A'] = df['A'].round(2)
df.style.bar(subset='A')
```

This returns

[image]

but I don't want all of those extra zeros displayed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to treat a styler as purely a rendering of the original dataframe. This means you can use a format to display the data rounded to 2 decimal places.

> The basic idea behind styling is that a user will want to modify the way the data is presented but still preserve the underlying format for further manipulation.

```
f = {'A':'{:.2f}'} #column col A to 2 decimals
df.style.format(f).bar(subset='A')
```

[image]

Read this [excellent tutorial](https://pbpython.com/styling-pandas.html) for exploring what all you can do with it and how.

**EDIT:** Added a formatting dict to show general use and to only apply the format to a single column.

Comment: If you wanted to change the decimal places of all the cells in the dataframe and still retain the styling, simply use `df.style.format(precision=2)`